# In Dataproc, whether or not the file prefix should be used when applying a property to job?

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc, dataproc

Actually the document explicitly states:

> [When applying a property to a job, the file prefix is not used.](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/cluster-properties#cluster_vs_job_properties)

However, the example given there is inconsistent with this

This is what the page says:

...However, many of these properties can also be applied to specific jobs. When applying a property to a job, the file prefix is not used.
The following example sets Spark executor memory to 4g for a Spark job **(spark: prefix omitted).**

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark \
    --region=region \
    --properties=spark.executor.memory=4g \
    ... other args ...
```

Job properties can be submitted in a file using the gcloud dataproc jobs submit job-type --properties-file flag (see, for example, the --properties-file description for an Hadoop job submission).

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit JOB_TYPE \
    --region=region \
    --properties-file=PROPERTIES_FILE \
    ... other args ...
```

The PROPERTIES_FILE is a set of line-delimited key=value pairs. The property to be set is the key, and the value to set the property to is the value. See the java.util.Properties class for a detailed description of the properties file format.

The following is an example of a properties file that can be passed to the --properties-file flag when submitting a Dataproc job.

```
dataproc:conda.env.config.uri=gs://some-bucket/environment.yaml
spark:spark.history.fs.logDirectory=gs://some-bucket
spark:spark.eventLog.dir=gs://some-bucket
capacity-scheduler:yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.adhoc.capacity=5
```

**Above the file prefixes are used in job properties**

Comment: Have you tried without adding file prefixes in `PROPERTIES_FILE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, property prefixes are only used for cluster properties and do not apply to job properties: https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/cluster-properties

Comment: Yes I have been through the link you provided. Can you tell me how the last example given on the same page makes sense in that case. Specifically : https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/cluster-properties#cluster_vs_job_properties:~:text=The%20following%20is%20an%20example%20of%20a%20properties%20file%20that%20can%20be%20passed%20to%20the%20%2D%2Dproperties%2Dfile%20flag%20when%20submitting%20a%20Dataproc%20job.

Comment: @figs_and_nuts this must be a bug in the doc, please report it via "Report error" functionality (button in the bottom right corner) on this doc page.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Igor, file prefixes are not used while applying property to a job. It is required on a cluster level when creating a cluster.

For the 2nd Dataproc job command mentioned ie.

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit JOB_TYPE \
    --region=region \
    --properties-file=PROPERTIES_FILE \
    ... other args ...
```

[this](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataproc/jobs/submit/hadoop#--properties-filehttps://) documentation gives details of using `PROPERTIES_FILE` which says that it specifies properties in the form of `property=value` in the text file, where property is the key and value is the value of that property ie. no file-prefix required.

Comment: I get this. My confusion arose from the inconsistent example that is given there which Igor has suggested I report as a bug. Do you think it is not a bug?

Comment: Yes, the doc needs an edit, hence it can be said that it's a bug.